# Reevaluate filter on timer in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-directive

I have a filter that I use to display relative time i.e. `5 mins ago`.  I want to be able to make this filter (or write a directive) to re-evaluate this every minute.  How can I do this?

JS Filter

```
m.filter('relativeTime', function () {
    return function (input, showAgo) {
        if (typeof showAgo == "undefined") {
            showAgo = true;
        }

        var dateMoment = input;
        if (typeof input == "string") {
            dateMoment = moment(input);
        }

        return dateMoment.fromNow(showAgo);
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<span class="relativeTime">{{activity.Time | relativeTime }}</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Although it's possible to create a stateful filter, the documentation [strongly advices](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) to make only stateless and idempotent filters. That's why a directive is a better idea here.

The principle is simple: when the directive is compiled, create a timer that will refresh the value every minute. The [`$interval` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) is perfect for that goal. However, as stated by the documentation, don't forget to destroy it when you don't need it any more.

```
MyApp.directive('relativeTime', function ($interval) {
    return {
        scope: {
            time: '=',
        },
        template: '<div>{{relativeTime}} secondes ago.</div>',
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.relativeTime = 0;

            var intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
                ++$scope.relativeTime;
            }, 1000);

            $scope.$watch('time', function (time) {
                var currentTime = new Date();
                $scope.relativeTime = Math.round((currentTime.getTime() - time.getTime()) / 1000);
            });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
            });
        },
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/pka05vb4/)</kbd>

For demonstration purposes, this directive is very simple and updated every second. But it's shouldn't be difficult to adapt it to your use case and in particular to your `date.fromNow()` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, is there anyway I can do it without a template? I'd ideally like a directive that just, somehow, re-evaluated all filters on the item I apply the directive to.  Or failing that just update the contents with the new relative time rather than have to specify a template (as I use this in various places where a specific template could cause problems)

Comment: @Chris I can't see how using a directive can cause problems, it's a simple `<div>` (or `<span>`, or whatever you want) here. Can you give me some details?